How to make UI Label with Email Text inside it clickable in .Net iOS
I have a .Net iOS application in which I have a Multiline UILabel with an email inside the entire text.
My requirement is to have a Tap on email only and I want to open Email App. For that I registered a Tap and tried to do as per the position but the touch position is not identified properly with below code.
Below is my XIB file.

private void OnEmailLabelTapped(UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        var location = recognizer.LocationInView(AlertMsg);
        var text = AlertMsg.Text;

        // Define the email address to look for
        var emailRange = new NSRange(text.IndexOf(Email), Email.Length);

        if (emailRange.Location == NSRange.NotFound)
        {
            // Email not found, nothing to handle
            return;
        }

        // Create attributed string for the whole text and get attributes
        var attributedText = new NSMutableAttributedString(text);
        var font = AlertMsg.Font;

        // Get the attributes for the email
        var emailAttributedText = new NSAttributedString(Email);

        // Create a Drawing Context to measure
        var textRect = attributedText.GetBoundingRect(
            new CGSize(AlertMsg.Frame.Width, nfloat.MaxValue),
            NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading,
            new NSStringDrawingContext());

        // Calculate Y position by checking each line
        var currentY = AlertMsg.Frame.Y;
        var emailYPosition = -1.0f; // To be adjusted if found

        // Iterate through the text to find Y position of email
        for (int i = 0; i < emailRange.Location; i++)
        {
            // Simulate getting the char's bounding box
            var charSize = new NSString(text.Substring(i, 1)).GetBoundingRect(
                new CGSize(nfloat.MaxValue, nfloat.MaxValue),
                NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, new UIStringAttributes { Font = AlertMsg.Font },
                new NSStringDrawingContext());

            if (currentY + charSize.Height >= location.Y)
            {
                // If the current upper Y with height is in bounds of the tap, set the email position
                emailYPosition = (float)currentY;
                break;
            }
            // Adjust the current Y position for the next character. This crude measurement assumes all characters have similar height.
            currentY += charSize.Height;
        }

        // Fine tune for the email itself
        if (emailYPosition != -1)
        {
            // Estimate Character Width for Email
            var emailRect = new CGRect(
                AlertMsg.Frame.X + emailRange.Location * (textRect.Width / text.Length), // Horizontal position
                emailYPosition,
                emailAttributedText.GetBoundingRect(new CGSize(nfloat.MaxValue, nfloat.MaxValue),
                NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading,
                new NSStringDrawingContext()).Width,
                font.LineHeight // assume the height is at least line height
            );

            // Check if the tap location is inside the email bounds
            if (emailRect.Contains(location))
            {
                // Handle opening email client
                OpenEmailClient(Email);
            }
        }
    }

How can I achieve this?

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.
